# Inconsistent gathering of data with google analytics using custom variables

Tags: google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

I am using Google analytics for my website which I am currently running locally.I have set custom variables on the signup as well as the login page. The problem is I am getting inconsistent data for the set custom variables at the Google Analytics.It does show some result but is very inconsistent.I am using google analytics plugin for PhoneGap .When checked the NSLog in the plugin section the data is passed on fine.Can anyone please help me out with this issue.Thanks